# Prove $(q → ((p \vee q) \wedge \tilde{} r) \equiv \tilde{} (q \wedge r)$ using the equivalence formulas. [SOLVED]

Tags: logic

How do I prove that  $$(q → ((p \vee q) \wedge \tilde{} r) \equiv \tilde{} (q \wedge r)$$
I cannot use the truth table to solve this and can only use the equivalence formulas: http://i58.tinypic.com/2e0kyhe.png (link to the formulas I'm allow to use for this problem)

So far I got:

I found out how to do it and will write it down here so it can help somebody else (maybe):

~q V ((p V q) Λ ~r)   Implication Elimination

~q V ((~r Λ p) V (~r Λ q)) Distributivity over Λ over V

I don't know to get rid of the P.

// EDIT

I found out how to solve it ;u; I'll post it here so it can maybe help others:

~q V ((p V q) Λ ~r)   Implication Elimination

(~q V q V p) Λ (~q V ~r)    Distributivity of V over Λ

(T V p) Λ (~q V ~r)      Complementation

T Λ (~ q V ~r)         Domination

~(q Λ r)

Comment: I have to prove without using the truth table.

Comment: So you should add that information in the question.

Comment: I'll keep that mind! Thank you!